# Dnf/Yum repository install on AIX 7.1 ImportError: 0509-022/0509-150 libcrypto

Tags: aix, dnf

I am trying to create a Yum/Dnf Repository for an offline AIX 7.1 and I've downloaded all the repos by using the `reposync` on a linux machine that was connected to the internet.
I've installed the Dnf bundle here: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/ezinstall/ppc/dnf_bundle_aix_71_72.tar and after an apparent successful install using the install_dnf.sh script, I get the following error when trying to install the `createrepo` package (`/opt/freeware/bin/dnf install createrepo`), necessary for creating the local repository on the AIX machine:

```
# /opt/freeware/bin/dnf install createrepo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/freeware/bin/dnf", line 57, in <module>
    from dnf.cli import main
  File "/opt/freeware/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    import dnf.base
  File "/opt/freeware/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 29, in <module>
    import libdn
    f.transaction
  File "/opt/freeware/lib/python3.7/site-packages/libdnf/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import common_types
  File "/opt/freeware/lib/python3.7/site-packages/libdnf/common_types.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _common_types
ImportError:    0509-022 Cannot load module /opt/freeware/lib/librepo.a(librepo.so.0).
        0509-150   Dependent module /opt/freeware/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.2) could not be loaded.
        0509-152   Member libcrypto.so.1.0.2 is not found in archive
        0509-022 Cannot load module /opt/freeware/lib/python3.7/site-packages/libdnf/_common_types.so.
        0509-150   Dependent module /opt/freeware/lib/librepo.a(librepo.so.0) could not be loaded.
```

While having this installed:

```
# rpm -qa
pci.df1000fd-2-10x8.noarch
lsof-4.61-4.ppc
ase-1.05-40.ppc
pci.df1000fa-1-191A5.noarch
NaCl-1.8.0.5-3.ppc
openssl-0.9.7l-1.ppc
bzip2-1.0.8-2.ppc
libtasn1-4.9-2.ppc
python3-3.7.9-0.ppc
libmodulemd-1.5.2-32_1.ppc
libsmartcols-2.34-32_1.ppc
librepo-1.11.0-32_1.ppc
libdnf-0.39.1-32_1.ppc
python3-hawkey-0.39.1-32_1.ppc
python3-libcomps-0.1.11-32_1.ppc
p11-kit-0.23.16-0.ppc
dnf-data-4.2.17-32_1.noarch
dnf-4.2.17-32_1.noarch
ca-certificates-2020.06.01-0.ppc
zlib-1.1.4-1.ppc
lpar2rrd-agent-4.95-7.ppc
rsync-2.6.2-1.ppc
pci.df1000f9-3-93a0.noarch
pci.df1080f9-1-91x4.noarch
popt-1.7-1.ppc
libgcc-6.3.0-2.ppc
libffi-3.2.1-3.ppc
AIX-rpm-7.1.5.33-15.ppc
libzstd-1.4.4-32_1.ppc
libsolv-0.7.9-32_1.ppc
zchunk-libs-1.1.4-32_1.ppc
rpm-python3-4.15.1-32_1.ppc
python3-libdnf-0.39.1-32_1.ppc
libcomps-0.1.11-32_1.ppc
python3-gpgme-1.13.1-32_1.ppc
p11-kit-tools-0.23.16-0.ppc
python3-dnf-4.2.17-32_1.noarch
dnf-automatic-4.2.17-32_1.noarch
python3-librepo-1.11.0-32_1.ppc
```

While I see that I have this file `/opt/freeware/lib/libcrypto.a` I don't see it's installed as a rpm.

**librepo.a** on the other hand seems to exist both as a rpm package and as a file on `/opt/freeware/lib/librepo.a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's trying to load `libcrypto.so.1.0.2` and `openssl-0.9.7l-1.ppc` is currently installed. Try to change the PATH so it will look for the system's `/usr/lib` first and only after that for `/opt/freeware/lib/`, as the OS, if it's **AIX 7.1** it should already have the required and most updated `libcrypto.so`